# If cluster node acting as a load balancing router fails, can we dircet future requests to any one active real server?

Tags: load-balancing, failover, lvs

For load balanced cluster that I am using, in case of router node fails, setup takes nearly 2 minutes until the VIP comes online on another running node (which earlier acted as real-server node).
All requests coming in this period are not handled.

To avoid this scenario, I was thinking weather it is possible to direct future requests on the VIP be served by any other cluster node until some specific period? If yes, how can I do it?

I am using direct routing technique, that means VIP is plumbed on all the real-server nodes.

Comment: Isn't that what load balancers are supposed to do?  Did you have some specific question or problem?

Comment: Load balancer is supposed to direct all requests to available real servers. that is true.